# ggplot2: Plotting Andrews curves

Tags: python, r, pandas, ggplot2

I am trying to learn about Andrews plots by doing. I know R has the `andrews` package that uses the base plotting system, but I wanted to use `ggplot2`. I followed the [`andrews_curves`](https://github.com/holoviz/hvplot/blob/master/hvplot/plotting/andrews_curves.py) function implementation in the `pandas` library.

I have managed to translate the data transformation steps of the Python function:

```
andrews <- function(df, class_column, samples=200) {
  t <- seq(-pi, pi, length.out = samples) 
  
  vals <- t(
    data.matrix(                    
      df[, -which(names(df) %in% class_column)]
    )
  )
  
  curves <- outer(vals[1, ], rep(1, length(t))) 
  
  for (i in 2:nrow(vals)) {                       
    ft = (i %/% 2) * t                          
    if (i %% 2 == 0) {                                
      curves <- curves + outer(vals[i, ], sin(ft))
    } else {
      curves <- curves + outer(vals[i, ], cos(ft))
    }  
  }
  
  df_out <- data.frame( 
    t = rep(seq_len(samples), nrow(curves)),
    sample =  rep(seq_len(nrow(curves)), ncol(curves)),
    values = as.vector(t(curves)),
    class_column = rep(df[, class_column], samples)
  ) 
  
  df_out 
}
```

Unfortunately, I am a beginner in Python and I do not understand the plotting systems (60-69 in [`andrews_curves`](https://github.com/holoviz/hvplot/blob/master/hvplot/plotting/andrews_curves.py)). I just want to replicate [this plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.plotting.andrews_curves.html) by using the same data, but I get something that is really off:

```r
iris <- read.csv('https://raw.github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/main/pandas/tests/io/data/csv/iris.csv')

adrews_data <- andrews(iris, "Name", 30)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(adrews_data, aes(x = t, y = values, color = class_column, group = interaction(class_column, sample))) +   
  geom_line(size = 1.2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that the oversight is that matrices in R are column-major and in python are row-major. In addition, you had hard-coded the iris dataset in your `df_out` specification whereas it was not a formal argument to the function.

```r
library(ggplot2)

andrews <- function(df, class_column, samples=200) {
  t <- seq(-pi, pi, length.out = samples) 
  
  vals <- t(
    data.matrix(                    
      df[, -which(names(df) %in% class_column)]
    )
  )
  
  curves <- outer(vals[1, ], rep(1, length(t))) 
  
  for (i in 2:nrow(vals)) {                       
    ft = (i %/% 2) * t                          
    if (i %% 2 == 0) {                                
      curves <- curves + outer(vals[i, ], sin(ft))
    } else {
      curves <- curves + outer(vals[i, ], cos(ft))
    }  
  }
  
  row <- as.vector(row(curves))
  col <- as.vector(col(curves))
  
  df_out <- data.frame(
    t = col,
    sample = row,
    values = as.vector(curves),
    class_column = df[[class_column]][row]
  )
  
  df_out 
} 

df <- andrews(iris, "Species")

ggplot(df, aes(x = t, y = values, color = class_column, 
               group = sample)) +   
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The code below seems to do what you want and, by eye, matches the plot on the Wikibedia page to which you link.

The only awkward piece was duplicating each row of the `iris` data frame for each value of `T` between -pi and pi.  It's critical that the value passed to `uncount()` is the same as the length of the vector `t`.

I've taken the order of the columns in the formula for the Andrews score of each row to be the order in which they appear in the `iris` data frame.  I don't know what effect changing the order of the columns would have.

```
library(tidyverse)

t=seq(-pi, pi, length.out=100)
root2 <- sqrt(2)
as_tibble(iris) %>%
  mutate(Row=row_number(), .before=1) %>% 
  uncount(100) %>% 
  add_column(T=rep(t, times=nrow(iris))) %>% 
  mutate(Andrews=Sepal.Length/root2 + Sepal.Width*sin(t) + Petal.Length*cos(t) + Petal.Width*sin(2*t)) %>% 
  ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(x=T, y=Andrews, group=Row, colour=Species))
```

giving

[image]

`group=Row` produces one line in the plot for each row of the data frame.  `colour=Species` colours each line according to the corresponding value of `Species`.

[There's probably a neater way than `uncount() %>% add_column()` of replicating each row of `iris` for each value of `t` using `expand()`, but I couldn't get it to work.]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will upvote it but not accept it as the solution, as it does not generalize to other data sets (e.g. when having more columns).  Indeed, there are many ways to do the andrews plots in ggplot2 (e.g. https://gist.github.com/yannabraham/5b71b9599b460968f72e9b7ae63868e7), but I am trying to replicate the `andrews_curves` function.

Comment: Ah!  I didn't realise that generalisability was key...

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, if you want a generalisable solution, you shouldn't end your question with 'I just want to replicate this plot {...}', which is verbatim what Limey showed how to do.